# Кастомное количество товаров для каждой категории (Битрикс)

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем добра! Как сделать доп. поле в админке категории сайта на битриксе, чтобы указывать своё "количество товаров" для вывода элементов на листинге. Т.е. мне надо выводить определенное кол-во товаров для каждой отдельной категории. Например, в категории-1 выводить по 30 товаров, в категории-2 по 50, а в категории-3 по 27, и т.д.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю надо создать переменную, добавить в условие вывода товаров, что если указано значение в этой переменной, то выводить указанное кол-во товаров, иначе выводить по-дефолту указанному в настройках компонента. Ну, и сделать доп. поле в админке тут /bitrix/modules/iblock/admin/iblock_section_edit.php чтобы указывать значение переменной.
Но как всё это реализовать, не хватает навыков. Я не программист, сеошник. Есть какие-то готовые возможно уже решения? Гуглил, чёт не могу найти.